# Anybody knows a good extendable open source web-crawler?

Tags: open-source, web-crawler

The crawler needs to have an extendable architecture to allow changing the internal process, like implementing new steps (pre-parser, parser, etc...)

I found the Heritrix Project (http://crawler.archive.org/).

But there are other nice projects like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176820/whats-a-good-web-crawler-tool

Comment: @LFSR Consulting. They are for different purposes...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/) is the best you can do when it comes to a free crawler.  It is built off of the concept of [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) (in an enterprise scaled manner) and is supported by the [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/core/) back end using [MapReduce](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html) (similar to Google) for large scale data querying.  Great products!  I am currently reading all about Hadoop in the new (not yet released) [Hadoop in Action](http://www.manning.com/lam/) from manning.  If you go this route I suggest getting onto their technical review team to get an early copy of this title!

These are all Java based.  If you are a .net guy (like me!!) then you might be more interested in [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), [Nutch.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnutch), and [Hadoop.NET](http://code.google.com/p/hadoopdotnet/) which are all class by class and api by api ports to C#.

Comment: +1 for Nutch and Hadoop, you can also look at solr if you are looking for distributed and scalable solution.

Comment: From the looks of it, Nutch.NET is completely non-existant and I couldn't even find a way to download it.

Comment: The same goes for Hadoop.NET, there isn't a single file for download

Answer (score 4):

You May also want to try Scrapy http://scrapy.org/

It is really easy to specify and run your crawlers.

Answer (score 1):

Abot is a good extensible web-crawler. Every part of the architecture is pluggable giving you complete control over its behavior. Its open source, free for commercial and personal use, written in C#.

https://github.com/sjdirect/abot

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered recently one called - [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied down to platform, I've had very good experiences with [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/) in the past.

It's written in Java and goes hand in hand with the Lucene indexer.