# how to copy contents of a website using a .net desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is this website on the net (this website is not built by me) which contains a grid and it is paged, so it spans many pages. I want the contents of each page of the grid in an excel sheet. It is a very cumbersome and not-so-very-smart way if I try to do it manually.

So is it possible to do this using a c#.net windows application?

Are there any freewares which would help me achieve this, something like a web crawler or a web spider or something like that?

Comment: LOL ripping off other people's websites. If you're going to do it, at least put in the hard yards and do it manually - your karma will marginally improve. Forgive me if I assume you're not going to ask the orignal author if you can ripoff his/her website.

Comment: @Pete855217 web scraping is a very common practice and there are many legitimate reasons to do it. It's not "ripping off" since anything you put on the internet is public and open.

Answer (score 2):

The term is called [Web Scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). and it is not an easy task to achieve using code.

You can use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to access and get the pages themselves. Then you can use regular expressions or something else like something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the data you need.

As for third party tools there are a lot of questions already answered on SO, but here's one you could take a look at: [What's a good Web Crawler tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176820/whats-a-good-web-crawler-tool)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to get the webpage using C#, and then use an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) query to extract the data you need. You'll need to know the correct way to format the query string in order to emulate the paging. If the table uses [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for paging you'll probably need to use some external tool/sniffer to find out the correct url/query string. I recommend the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox to do this.

Once you have extracted the HTML table via XPath, you could use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) to transform it into [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format. From CSV it is very easy to import it into Excel using [Office Interop](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084).